# MySQL selects wrong result when the field value multiply with number

Tags: mysql

I have used a multiplication in my select query. But the query return wrong value with additional decimal value to original value

Here is my query

```
SELECT `value` AS `original_value`, `value` * 100 AS `multiplied_value` FROM `data_table`;
```

And the result is

[image]

Whats wrong with the select?

Comment: you must round multiplied value ROUND(`value` * 100, 1) AS `multiplied_value`

Comment: can you show us table data structure

Comment: @Zeljka The value field is 'FLOAT'

Comment: when you store data as float, it store original data for example its stores -2.799 but it shows as -2.8.. you just need to round data on select like I wrote.. Or original_value set as decimal data type

Comment: float data type is better for rounding errors, but if you need rounded  example -2.8 then you need decimal data type, not float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your column is of a float data type.

You have to CAST the value column as integers/decimals rather than as floats.

```
(CAST(value AS Decimal(5,2)) * 100 AS `multiplied_value`
```